# 'magic' links / meta-tags to tag info pages

Tags: feature-request, tags, markdown, tag-wiki, hyperlinks

I very often use the `[ask]` tag on SO to refer to how posts should be made. But I more and more find the need to refer to the info page of a specific tag since these info pages also contain contain valuable information at least for the tags I'm interested in. I know I can use something like `[tag:tagname]`, but it would be way more interesting to also be able to do something like `[info:tagname]` that would then link to the `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/<tagname>/info` page. These info pages could/should contain valuable information for posters to be referred to.

Comment: I would definitely use this feature. It might need some visual indication that it's a link to the tag info page, to differentiate it from normal tag styling though.

Comment: This is very useful within tag wiki pages themselves to refer to another tag and differentiate between that tag and the other for example (that way the link links directly to the wiki instead of the latest questions). But maybe we could use something like `[wiki:tagname]` instead.